# Number() not converting floating points from db correct

Tags: node.js, typescript, typebox, sinclair

I am using `sinclair/typebox` for TypeScript project, here is my schema:

```
export const ItemValue = Type.Object({
  itemBalance: Type.Number()
}) 

export type ItemValueType = Static<typeof ItemValue>;
```

how I am reading this data from oracle db:

```
const result = await connection.execut<ItemValueType>(query, {
{
  outFormat: OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
}
})
```

The issue is that there is a value in oracle `15.79` which is being returned as `15.790000000000001`

any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't see any issues to fix.  Welcome to floating point operations.  This is a dense topic.  In a nutshell, floating-point values not always have an exact binary representation.  You are probably hitting one of such cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Format your numbers to a certain number of decimal places before displaying them.

Comment: I am not making any calculation, I am reading from db and spitting it out in json, did't expect it to happen in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `TO_CHAR` function in my query like so:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(my_column, 'FM99.99') as myColumn from myTable
```

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
let n = 15.790000000000001;
let m = n.toFixed(2);
document.write(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you’re facing with the precision of floating-point numbers is common when dealing with numerical data.

One way to address this is by rounding the number to a specific decimal precision. You can use the `toFixed()` method to round the number to a fixed number of decimal places.

You can modify your code to round the `itemBalance` value like:

```
const result = await connection.execut<ItemValueType>(query, {
  {
    outFormat: OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
  }
});


if (result.itemBalance !== undefined) {
  result.itemBalance = Number(result.itemBalance.toFixed(2)); // Rounding to 2 decimal places
}
```

This will round the itemBalance value to two decimal places before further processing, ensuring consistent precision.